# How to make a synchronized HttpRequest in Android?

Tags: android, http, synchronization

I want to execute a function which holds the connection with the server.
When there are some new messages coming out, I should receive a method. Our iOS version uses a synchronized Request to control this method, but how could do it in Android?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. Please revert my changes if you feel it lost its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Try [HTTPRequestExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpRequestExecutor.html), whose method [execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpRequestExecutor.html#execute%28org.apache.http.HttpRequest,%20org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29) can:

> Synchronously send a request and obtain the response.

Check out this link for an example of how to implement it: http://www.androidadb.com/class/ht/HttpRequestExecutor.html

Comment: Thank you.I have tried this method which uses HTTPRequestExecutor.But when I change the stream on the server,the application of Android can't receive the change

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "you can't" because the display thread won't allow you to make HTTP requests. The longer answer is, as long as you don't mind the "sync" part of the call being in a thread, you can use apache commons and just make a server call that blocks while it's GETTING/POSTING the data.  However, you'll still need to give the Thread a Runnable callback which it will call when its done with the request.

Comment: Thank you.In the past ,I used a AsyTask or handler to achieve the function.But now,I want to make a long poll,so I want to use synchronized method.Certainly,it should be write in other method,but I still don't know the way to do.I can hardly find the right answer in appache commons or java.util.net.

Comment: AsyncTask is just a wrapper around a Thread (it has some nice features to know when it's done doing what you want it to do).  The issue is that Android after 3.0 will not allow you to make network calls on the main (display) thread. So, you have no choice but to spawn *some alternate thread to make your network calls. However, if your ambition is a long poll, then blocking is not the answer. I would urge you to use a socket instead. Much more effective for continuous back and forth data exchange to the server.